# How to create wild card subdomains in Localhost apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

In my project i need to check the subdomains against a white list of allowed subdomains, and redirect them to the correct page, if the subdomain is not in the white list i need to redirect them to a 'account not found' page

currently im writing `127.0.0.1 sub.example.com` and `127.0.0.1 sub1.example.com` in the etc/hosts file

how do i use the * (wild card) parameter here, the /etc/apach2/sites-available folder is able to change the root directory but i'm unable to use * wild card entry here

- how do i use wild card parameter in localhost
- in production environment what is the best practice

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild card subdomains are implemented by DNS hosting provider, the setup would depend on your hosting provider, what you are looking for is [Name-Based virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html) . on your local machine you could try this [xip.io](http://xip.io/) it redirects all your subdomains to one single IP address